# how to merge URL with root

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

This is kind of dumb question. I'm hoping to get some quick answers for this.

I'm trying to to access files via FTP who's path is as follows:

```
/contents/member/PetePentreath/photos/thumbs/0d136985-1.png"
```

I'm trying write a path that includes the root of the file directory. I'm using `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath);` and concatenating it with the path to the file which gives me the output as follows:

```
"E:\\Downloads\\YourTimeSite\\YourTimeSite\\/contents/member/PetePentreath/photos/thumbs/0d136985-1.png"
```

This isn't the right format for the url. What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try changing the '/' in the string that hold "/contents/member/PetePentreath/photos/thumbs/0d136985-1.png" to '\'? You can do that in C# with String.Replace.

Then, concatenate it with the call to HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath), this should return the correct path.